# Incrementing iterator from end to begin

Tags: c++, iterator

I want to iterate over a vector and when reaching the end it should loop back to the front.

This is a small example which does not compile

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int>::iterator Next(const std::vector<int>& vec, 
    const std::vector<int>::iterator it) 
{
    auto itNext = it+1;
    if (itNext == vec.end())
        itNext = vec.begin(); // breaks 
    return itNext;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector x{0, 2, 3, 4};
    auto it = x.begin()+1;        
    return *Next(x,it);
}
```

and here a [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/asP34v439).

The issue arises because of no available conversion between `vector::const_iterator` (result of `begin()`) and `vector::iterator`.
How can one fix this issue?

Comment: should the function return a `const_iterator` or an `iterator` ?

Comment: Did you try and pass `vec` by non-`const` reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert a `const_iterator` to an `iterator` because this would break const-correctness.

You basically have two options. When it is ok to return a `const_iterator` then return a `const_iterator`:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int>::const_iterator Next(const std::vector<int>& vec, 
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator it) 
{
    auto itNext = it+1;
    if (itNext == vec.end())
        itNext = vec.begin();
    return itNext;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector x{0, 2, 3, 4};
    auto it = x.begin()+1;        
    return *Next(x,it);
}
```

You can only get a `const_iterator` from a `const std::vector&`. Hence if you want to return an `iterator` the vector has to be passes as non-const reference:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int>::iterator Next(std::vector<int>& vec, 
    std::vector<int>::iterator it) 
{
    auto itNext = it+1;
    if (itNext == vec.end())
        itNext = vec.begin(); 
    return itNext;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector x{0, 2, 3, 4};
    auto it = x.begin()+1;        
    return *Next(x,it);
}
```

---

To have both in one I would pass iterators and make the function a template, so it can be used with `iterator` or `const_iterator`. The function might grant you non-const access to the vectors elements, but for the function itself it doesn't matter that much if the iterators are const or not.

```
#include <vector>


template <typename IT>
IT Next(IT it,IT begin,IT end) {
    auto itNext = it+1;
    return (itNext == end) ? begin : itNext;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector x{0, 2, 3, 4};
    auto it = x.begin()+1;        
    auto it2 = Next(it,x.begin(),x.end());
    *it2 = 42;
}
```

Comment: "Passing the std::vector as non-const reference is not nice, because the function is not actually modifying the vector" But it is giving you mutable access to the vector's elements

Comment: @Caleth right. Its poor wording. The point is that `IT Next(IT it,IT begin,IT end)` works for `iterator`s as well as `const_iterator`s and the constness of the iterators is not that relevant for the function